# Extracting Script Information for Web Scraping Code

Tags: python-3.x, web, tags, extract, screen-scraping

I managed to isolate this tag shown below and I'm trying to extract the product title, sale price, and stock information as variables.
Its type is class 'bs4.element.Tag'

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var utag_data = {page_breadcrumb:'Home &gt; Components &gt; Computer Cases &gt; Computer Cases &gt; Fractal Design &gt; Item#:N82E16811352069',
            page_tab_name:'Components',
            product_category_id:['9'],
            product_category_name:['Computer Cases'],
            product_subcategory_id:['7'],
            product_subcategory_name:['Computer Cases'],
            product_id:['11-352-069'],
            product_web_id:['N82E16811352069'],
            product_title:['Fractal Design Focus G Black ATX Mid Tower Computer Case'],
            product_manufacture:['Fractal Design'],
            product_sale_price:['99.99'],
            product_default_shipping_cost:['12.99'],
            product_model:['FD-CA-FOCUS-BK-W'],
            product_instock:['1'],
            product_group_id:['6055851'],
            page_type:'Product',
            site_region:'CAN',
            site_currency:'CAD',
            page_name:'NewProductDetail',
            search_scope:jQuery('#haQuickSearchStore option:selected').text(),
            user_nvtc:Web.StateManager.Cookies.get(Web.StateManager.Cookies.Name.NVTC),
            user_name:Web.StateManager.Cookies.get(Web.StateManager.Cookies.Name.LOGIN,'LOGINID6'),
            third_party_render:[]

      };
          var description = Biz.Common.QuickSearch.getUrlSearch('Description');
      var d = Biz.Common.QuickSearch.getUrlSearch('d');
      if(description)
      {
         utag_data.search_keyword = description;
      }
      else if(d)
      {
         utag_data.search_keyword = d;
      }
      </script>
```

I'm having trouble accessing the utag_data. I haven't been able to index the product info using numbers or by calling the header. The contents of the entire script seem to be stored in one entry.

Answer (score 0):

> managed to isolate this tag

I'd recommend to apply regex to the isolated tag content.

```
/utag_data = {([^}]+)};/
```

The first group will contain the target data:

```
page_breadcrumb:'Home &gt; Components &gt; Computer Cases &gt; Computer Cases &gt; Fractal Design &gt; Item#:N82E16811352069',\n            page_tab_name:'Components',\n            product_category_id:['9'],\n            product_category_name:['Computer Cases'],\n            product_subcategory_id:['7'],\n            product_subcategory_name:['Computer Cases'],\n            product_id:['11-352-069'],\n            product_web_id:['N82E16811352069'],\n            product_title:['Fractal Design Focus G Black ATX Mid Tower Computer Case'],\n            product_manufacture:['Fractal Design'],\n            product_sale_price:['99.99'],\n            product_default_shipping_cost:['12.99'],\n            product_model:['FD-CA-FOCUS-BK-W'],\n            product_instock:['1'],\n            product_group_id:['6055851'],\n            page_type:'Product',\n            site_region:'CAN',\n            site_currency:'CAD',\n            page_name:'NewProductDetail',\n            search_scope:jQuery('#haQuickSearchStore option:selected').text(),\n            user_nvtc:Web.StateManager.Cookies.get(Web.StateManager.Cookies.Name.NVTC),\n            user_name:Web.StateManager.Cookies.get(Web.StateManager.Cookies.Name.LOGIN,'LOGINID6'),\n            third_party_render:[]\n\n
```

Then split it by semicolon `;`  and extract from key-values by splitting by `:`.